# conversion latitude/longitude into distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinate-transformation

My problem is a bit tricky, apologyze if my question isn't clear at all.

I use googleMap v3 API. the user can clique on the map to create a mark , if he click on the mark , i give latitude & longitude info into a infoWindow (this is done and it's OK)

The things a try to do : the user can give dimension (km/miles) and I have to draw a rectangle of the given size (the create mark shoud be the middle of the area). The probleme come from latlng or bounds who take only latitude & longitude. so I try to convert it.

here is the main part of the code.

```
//latitude
// 1°lat = 111,11 km
//for me: 1km = 0.00900 .

//longitude
//1°lat =  111,11 km * cos latitude
// for me : 1 km = ((1/Math.cos(latitude)) /111.11)

var myBounds = new Array();

var longkm = 5;
var largkm = 2;
myBounds[0] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat()-(0.009*longkm), positionmarqueur.lng()-(Math.abs(((1/Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat()-(0.009*longkm))) /111.11))*largkm)),
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat()+(0.009*longkm), positionmarqueur.lng()+(Math.abs(((1/Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat()+(0.009*longkm))) /111.11))*largkm))
);

var overlay1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: myBounds[0],
    strokeColor: "green",
    strokeWeight: 1
});

var longkm = 10;
var largkm = 10;
myBounds[1] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat()-(0.009*longkm), positionmarqueur.lng()-(Math.abs(((1/Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat()-(0.009*longkm))) /111.11))*largkm)),
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat()+(0.009*longkm), positionmarqueur.lng()+(Math.abs(((1/Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat()+(0.009*longkm))) /111.11))*largkm))
);

var overlay2 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: myBounds[1],
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 1
});
```

This shoud draw a 5,2 rectanle and a 10,10 rectangle(well , a 10km square)
(for info : var positionmarqueur = latLng; above in the code)

if I take a look to the result : the first rectangle look more than a 50/20 km. (did i do a mistake when i divide? with a 10 factor? i'm not very good in mathematic, but it look correct).

The seconde.... just look like a 200*40 km rectangle ....

So. Where is the probleme? Is the formule wrong ? Or i'm just dumb and i miss something ?

Thinqs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm to use is

```
  var largkm = 5,
      longkm = 10;

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat() - ((largkm/2)/110.54), positionmarqueur.lng() - ((longkm/2)/(Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat())*111.32))),
    new google.maps.LatLng(positionmarqueur.lat() + ((largkm/2)/110.54), positionmarqueur.lng() + ((longkm/2)/(Math.cos(positionmarqueur.lat())*111.32)))
  );
```

(*note: i am dividing the rectangle size by 2 since we are defining the bounds from the center*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/a5QVM/

---

**Update**

You should use the google geometry library which uses whatever projection the google maps use, so transformations will be accurate. (*you will need to change the URL for the google API to `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false`*)

More specific you should use the [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) method

```
var rectbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    spherical.computeOffset(spherical.computeOffset(positionmarqueur, longkm*1000/2, -90),largkm*1000/2,0),
    spherical.computeOffset(spherical.computeOffset(positionmarqueur, longkm*1000/2, 90), largkm*1000/2,180)
);
```

**Updated demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/a5QVM/10/
(*the `*1000` is to  convert the distance to meters as that is what is expected from the `computeOffset` method*)

Comment: there is a trick if you use Clermont-ferrand position (45.7581263,3.1317803) . I will edit the jsfiddle & valid answer

Comment: Are you sure about the formula? i mean , if you draw a 100/100km , it's trully not a square, it's a rectangle, do it come from javascript approximation ? Or i see it like this on googlemap because of earth inclination?

Comment: @ssbb updated answer with a more accurate solution (*which uses google methods to make the transformation*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli when I use the spherical bounds and invoke `LatLngBounds.getSouthWest()` and `getNorthEast()` I get the NorthWest and SouthEast bounds?  What is happening to have these reversed - http://jsfiddle.net/mtpultz/dspqxLzr/24/.  I added console logging.

Comment: It seems to fix the issue if I switch 0 and 180 in the equation - http://jsfiddle.net/mtpultz/dspqxLzr/29/